# How to extract date from timestamp field in hive

Tags: sql, hive, timestamp, bigdata, hiveql

Timestamp column is : 20210817 16:45

I want to extract only date part using Hive query language.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Using regexp_replace:

```
select date(regexp_replace('20210817 16:45', '^(\\d{4})(\\d{2})(\\d{2}).*','$1-$2-$3'))
```

Result:

```
2021-08-17
```

Note: `date()` function is not necessary here, string in `yyyy-MM-dd` is fully compatible with Hive date type.